# How to trigger oninput during onwheel event without using eval?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I trigger an element's `oninput` event during an `onwheel` event?

## XML

```
<input max="10" min="-10" oninput="a_function('param string',param_obj);" type="range" value="0" />
```

## JavaScript

```
window.onwheel = function(event)
{
 if (event.target.nodeName == 'input' && event.target.getAttribute('type') == 'range')
 {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaY < 0 || event.deltaX > 0) {event.target.stepUp();}
  else if (event.deltaY > 0 || event.deltaX < 0) {event.target.stepDown();}
 }
}
```

I am considering using something along the lines of:

```
if (event.target.hasAttribute('oninput')) {}
```

...and parsing the functions and parameters such as `window['a_function']('param string',param_obj);` however I'm not sure how reliable that will be or how extensive that would get in regards to things like `this`.

Absolutely no frameworks, libraries or use of `eval()` and am not interested in `addEventListener`.

Comment: It's not clear  what you mean triggering an element's input event. You can dispatch events programatically but there are limitations, you can't trigger events the same way actual user input can. Are you trying to control a range input with the mouse wheel?

Comment: @skyline3000 The `oninput` event does not trigger for the `onwheel` event even though the wheel event is changing the value. The initial event (`wheel` works) though the browser is bugged and not triggering the `oninput` event.

Comment: Are you looking for this behaviour [Check this Link](https://codepen.io/stoi2m1/pen/QKELpj)

Comment: @user2932057 Yes though I absolutely can not use frameworks or libraries.

Comment: Which browser/OS exposes this behavior of controlling the range input through wheel natively? I don't have it on any of my browsers on macOs. And if the input event is not fired there, that's probably a browser bug, let them know about it.

Comment: @Kaiido All work with the JavaScript code above. Gecko is bugged scrolling up (sets values +70, +200, etc instead of the `step` but posting bugs for Mozilla is a waste of time). IE11 crashes, at least on my rig. The results vary & I've introduced two `data-*` HTML5 attributes to compensate for the issue. On top of all that Blink/Chrome forces the `wheel` event to be passive and that garbage needs to be ripped out. It's bad enough people don't know how to write code but when they actively limit what we can do. All the tools in the world don't help if physics does not cooperate at every chance.